# Передача текста из своего приложения на Youtube

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

Как передать текст через неявный интент, чтобы он попадал прямиком в поисковой запрос в приложение Youtube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
intent.putExtra("query", "some query string");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Только не забудьте обернуть `startActivity(intent)` в

```
try {
    ...
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    ...
}
```

на случай, если приложение YouTube не установлено на устройстве.